# How do I send an email with a thumbnail using smtp?

Tags: node.js, smtp, webmail

When ever I send an email using the SMTP the receiver receives it without a thumbnail mostly Gmail would set it to a "?" which makes the emails look very sketchy. How do I add my logo/avatar for thumbnail of my emails?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a vCard that contains an embedded GIF image encoded in base64 format that travels within the vCard itself; not the email.

```
...
--content-boundary-mixed
Content-Type: text/v-card; name="vCard.vcf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7-bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="vCard.vcf"

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:First Middle Last
N;CHARSET=UTF-8:Last;First;Middle;Mr.;III
NICKNAME;CHARSET=UTF-8:user1
GENDER:O
UID;CHARSET=UTF-8:c460ac7c-1fd9-4fe1-89ed-17f0d2006df1
EMAIL;CHARSET=UTF-8;type=WORK,INTERNET:user1@example.com
LOGO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=GIF:R0lGODdhYABgAPAAABteIMlFJiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAABgAGAAAAJ
 uhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjU
 qn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLiIUgAAO
 w==
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=GIF:R0lGODdhYABgAPAAALccHMlFJiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAABgAGAAAA
 JuhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJj
 Uqn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLiIUgAA
 Ow==
TEL;TYPE=CELL:(801) 333-3333
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(801) 555-5555
LABEL;CHARSET=UTF-8;TYPE=WORK:123 Main St\nSalt Lake City\, UT 84101
ADR;CHARSET=UTF-8;TYPE=WORK:;;123 Main St;Salt Lake City;UT;84101;United Sta
 tes of America
TITLE;CHARSET=UTF-8:Systems Administrator
ORG;CHARSET=UTF-8:XYZ Inc.
URL;type=WORK;CHARSET=UTF-8:https://www.example.com
NOTE;CHARSET=UTF-8:Just a personal note.
REV:2021-04-10T15:21:18.119Z
END:VCARD
--content-boundary-mixed--
```

Answer (score 0):

SMTP does not support a way to send the profile/contact picture along.

A partial solution is to create a GSuite account (commercial), this gives businesses the chance to use gmail for their own domain names.

And it will also let you set a pictures for your business accounts.

But it's not a complete solution. While other gmail and gsuite users will see this picture when they receive your e-mail, it won't work for all e-mail clients and providers.

What you could do as a (rather poor) alternative, is to send a vCard along with your e-mail. That's like a digital business card.

Comment: This seems like a weird workaround. Gmail _does_ provide for a way to attach an identity icon to your message. You have to have a GMail account and designate any email address you have control over as a secondary email address for that account. See e.g. https://cowbelly.com/gmail-profile-photo/

Comment: @suchislife answers of other users can be edited to correct spelling or grammar mistakes or to correct broken URLs. But this feature is not intended for modifying or adding content to the answer. - So, I rolled it back.